# How to add wysiwyg editor in custom generated gutenberg block in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block

Is there any way to add `WYSIWYG Editor` in a custom generated `Gutenberg block` in WordPress. I had searched in google and only found how to add Richtext editor to the custom block. What i need is a complete WYSIWYG editor like below.

[image]